# How to turn base 64 html image into binary

Tags: c++, image, qt

I am using Qt on Windows and I want to turn this part here:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```

into the native binary encoding of a .png file. I have already isolated the `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA...` part as a QString, my only question is how to convert that into say, a QByteArray that can be written to a file. Specifically, a .png file. The QByteArray::fromBase64 method is what I tried, it doesn't work.

So my code is:

```
QDataStream stream(&file);
QByteArray qba;
qba.append(sourcestring);
stream << QByteArray::fromBase64(qba);
```

sourcestring is the source string (with the data:image/png;base64, part removed) and file is the png file I am writing to.

Comment: what does 'It doesn't work' mean? I doubt that QT fromBase64() does not work...

Comment: @user0042 I added a small example

Comment: @OznOg I added a small example to show how it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might do this:

```
QString s("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAl...");
QByteArray ba = QByteArray::fromBase64(s.toUtf8());
QImage img = QImage::fromData(ba);
img.save("test.png");
```